# Enabling extensions in Chrome on a Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, browser-addons

I already know how to enable extensions in Chrome on Windows (by adding the **--enable-extensions** command line parameter).

My question is how to do this on a Mac? Are Chrome extensions even supported at this point on the Mac? If so, how can I go about adding this command-line parameter, without having to launch Chrome from the Terminal every time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extensions are now enabled in the [Chrome Developer Channel](http://dev.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel) for the Mac.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome extensions are not yet supported on the Mac.

Comment: That's what I was suspecting, but thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

So, extensions aren't supported in the Google Chrome app for Mac, but the latest Chromium build supports extensions.

You can get chromium at http://www.chromium.org/

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://grack.com/blog/2009/12/08/re-enable-install-button-for-mac-chrome-extensions/
I tried here and it worked.

Comment: This is no longer necessary

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and type:

```
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --enable-easy-off-store-extension-install
```

now you are allowed to install extensions (crx files) that are not in the Chrome Web Store during this session of Chrome.